# How to use MCPE /give command with add enchant attribute?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

The new beta 1.0.5 has introduced /give command.
How do I add the enchant attribute?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to to /give a weapon object that has an enchantment on it?

Comment: Yup in minecraft pocket edition

Answer (score 0):

Components are in JSON format. However, some of the ones on PC don't exactly work as suspected.

Example of JSON format:

```
{"fieldname":"field content"}
```

or

```
{"field":123}
```

Comment: Does this make use of the give command? How? Can you illustrate that?

Comment: After a couple years, I have determined that my answer is, in fact, probably a bad answer. I was attempting to illustrate the format used in Pocket Edition commands (and also in Java commands). In short, this ain't it, chief, it does not help to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Say you want a sword with max sharpness and unbreaking, this is the command:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:32767},{id:21,lvl:32767}]}
```

If it doesn't work, then I don't know.